# Possible .htaccess errors, 1and1.com not rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following .htaccess file works perfectly on my local server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.cssc
RewriteRule . style.php [L]

RewriteRule ^admin\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . admin.php [L]
```

I am doing some work for a client and he is using 1and1.com. I do not know anything about his account or what package he has.

All files are rewritten to admin.php (unless they actually exist). The problem is, I am getting a 404.

I know it's reading the .htaccess file because:

1. I can put garbage in the file and get a 500 error.
2. If I do a general rewrite (all pages go to admin.php), it works.

Also, it seems that 1and1 does it's own rewriting. If I go to: `http://somewhere/afile`, it will include `afile.js` even though I am not requesting the `.js`.It is super strange.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or any insight?

Comment: Very disappointing service of 1and1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply "Do not nest .htaccess files". I had one in a sub folder.

Answer (score 1):

To add some information..

1and1 seem to have some sort of default rewriting already in place that can interfere with your own rules - for example:
`RewriteRule ^product$                         /product.php                        [L]`

It gave a 404 for this, and also for any other rewrite rule that matched a pre-existing .php file in my root folder.

2 things that 'fixed' it:

Change rewrite text to no longer match filename:
`RewriteRule ^productz$                         /product.php                        [L]`

Or, change filename: 
`RewriteRule ^product$                         /product_.php                        [L]`

Both work - both very annoying.